# Correct behavior for string literal concatenation (C++11 phase 6 of translation)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I'm pretty sure that Visual C++ 2015 has a bug here, but I don't feel 100% sure.

Code:

```
// Encoding: UTF-8 with BOM (required by Visual C++).
#include <stdlib.h>

auto main()
    -> int
{
    auto const s = L""
        " is not in the Unicode BMP!";
    return s[0] > 256? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Result with g++:

```
[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> g++ --version | find "++"
g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> g++ compiler_bug_demo.cpp

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> run a
Process exit code = 0.

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> _
```

Result with Visual C++:

```
[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> cl /nologo- 2>&1 | find "++"
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> cl compiler_bug_demo.cpp /Feb
compiler_bug_demo.cpp
compiler_bug_demo.cpp(8): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\U00010437' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> run b
Process exit code = 1.

[H:\scratchpad\simple_text_io]
> _
```

Is there any UB involved, and if not, which compiler behaves correctly?

**Addendum:**

The behavior is unchanged for both compilers if use lowercase greek PI, “π”, which *is* in the BMP, so that doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I was about to say "VC++ is wrong because §2.14.5, item 13", but the rules surrounding character sets always confuse me.

Comment: VS 2015 update 3 (`Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24213.1 for x86`) compiles this with no errors or warnings; I saved the file in `utf-8-unix` coding system in Emacs. Which version of VS do you specifically have?

Comment: @legends2k: The example in the question lists the version.

Comment: It has the compiler's version, yes, but not Visual Studio's version. Update 2, 3, or without any updates, etc.

Comment: Oh. I'm pretty sure I never installed update 3, due to the infra-structure for snooping they built into that. It just greatly annoyed me. But then, every time in the past, since the early 1990s, me being annoyed by some Microsoft half-dishonesty has always passed. I just have to let it sort of diffuse out. But anyway, it's the compiler version and build that matters, and only that. And that's included in the largish version number.

Comment: @Danh: With the source file as UTF-8 without BOM, you're just misinforming Visual C++, telling it that the source encoding is Windows ANSI. And that predicts and explains your result.

Comment: @Danh: Yes. With BOM, as a matter of course, since that's required by Visual C++, and supported by g++.

Comment: I think it's the same case with @legends2k

Answer (score 2):

From **[lex.string]**:

> 13. In translation phase 6, adjacent string literals are concatenated. If both string literals have the same encoding-prefix, the resulting concatenated string literal has that encoding-prefix. **If one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand.** If a UTF-8 string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal token, the program is ill-formed. Any other
>       concatenations are conditionally-supported with implementation-defined behavior. [ Note: This concatenation is an interpretation, not a conversion. Because the interpretation happens in translation phase 6 (after
>       each character from a literal has been translated into a value from the appropriate character set), a string literal’s initial rawness has no effect on the interpretation or well-formedness of the concatenation. —end
>       note ] Table 8 has some examples of valid concatenations.

So there is no UB here, however phase 5 of translation might have already changed values of some characters:

> 5. **Each** source character set **member in a** character literal or a **string literal**, as well as each escape sequence and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is **converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to an implementation-defined member** other than the null (wide) character.

Comment: Yes, the phase 5 thing is unclear to me. By this time all basic source character set characters have been translated to (effectively) Unicode, but there can be left "source character set" characters that are not in the "basic source character set"? One difference between g++ and Visual C++ is that g++ defaults to UTF-8 as its execution character set, while Visual C++ defaults to Windows ANSI (in my case codepage 1252). But such translation would wreak havoc with wide string literals in general!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is probably intentionally vague to not limit implementations what they do support and what not. For example, you can have compiler with 16bit wide chars to ignore characters not from BMP. (which might be what happens here)